# Mostrar mas de un resultado json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
function OrdersCallback(json) {
for (var o = 0; o < json.length; o++) {
$('#summary').append('<b>Order Number:</b> ' + json[o].order_number + '<br />');
$('#summary').append('<b>Item:</b> ' + json[o].line_items[0].name + '<br />');
$('#summary').append('<b>Customer:</b> ' + json[o].customer.billing_address.first_name + '<br />');
$('#summary').append('<b>Status:</b> ' + json[o].status + '<br />');
$('#summary').append('<b>Total:</b> ' + json[o].total + '<br />');
$('#summary').append('<hr />');
}
}
```

en la siguiente

```
$('#summary').append('<b>Item:</b> ' + json[o].line_items[0].name + '<br />');
```

hay mas de un resultado, pero no se como mostrar todos, muestra solo el 1.

aqui mi codigo

https://jsfiddle.net/JDLA1/hqvbydz9/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aplicando el método [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) para Iterar los Objetos devueltos por `json[o].line_items` y  `JOIN` para separar los elementos devueltos `(",")`

```
 $('#summary').append('<b>Item:</b> ' + 
               json[o].line_items.map(function(elem){
                      return elem.name;
               }).join(",") + '<br />');
```

Comment: Gracias! @dev-joel sos Grande! :)